# SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup not working when claims authentication is enabled

Tags: security, claims-based-auth, groups, claims

Method `SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup` can be used to resolve users that belongs to a AD Group. However, when claims authentication is enabled, this method doesn't work as expected. Is there another way to make this method work, or another workaround to resolve users membership for Claims based Applications?

It would be great if responses include a workaround that works as well for claims. That means, expand (resolve) all users that has a particular claim.

Comment: I would really love so see this answered, I'm currently having the same problem and I can't seem to be able to find a proper solution to this.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail on what exactly is not working. Are you trying to check if a user is a member of AD group or trying to retrieve all members of an AD group.